# how to pass picklist value in Dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I am using dynamic soql where I am reading the conditions from an XML and getting those as a String
but I am not able to find it who the query will structure

```
String query = 'SELECT id, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Status__c =: InProgress';
Database.query(query);
```

It throws error message as

> System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: InProgress

Answer (score 5):

use [variable binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)

```
String status = 'InProgress';
String query = 'SELECT id, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Status__c = :status';
List<CustomObject__c> result = Database.query(query);
```

it is preferable to use variable binding than string concatenation in order to prevent [SOQL Injections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm). Also, if it not necessary to use dynamic SOQL use static SOQL.

```
String status = 'InProgress';
List<CustomObject__c> result = [
    select id, Name
    from CustomObject__c
    where Status__c =:status
    ];
```

Comment: actually all the fields I am reading from compact layout and all the where condition I am reading from a xml file store in one object record and passing it to the the dynamic soql so not sure who I will do it..

Answer (score 1):

As [Alexander](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/22425/alexander-berehovskiy) said in his [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/200528/12408), use variable binding or static SOQL.

If you do need to use dynamic SOQL without variables, you will need to add these values as a string(=escaping single quotes):

```
String query = 'SELECT id, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Status__c = \'InProgress\'';
```

Note, that I removed `:` from the query, which is used by Apex to understand that you are using a variable there.

Answer (score -1):

You must add InProgess in quotes('InProgress').

String query = 'SELECT id, Name FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Status__c =: 'InProgress' ';
Database.query(query);

Comment: your code will give compilation error